# How to release resources for a broadcast receiver after it has been used?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have been trying to work out how to clear a broadcast receiver after it has been used. My app currently has the broadcast receiver registered within the Android Manifest and then I am calling it using an intent , to a PendingIntent and then from there I use an AlarmManager , this then triggers the Broadcast receiver at the specified time,

However I feel that when the time occurs and the broadcast receiver has been processed, it is then left in memory unused.

I have read other posts and articles about unregistering the broadcast receiver from the activity it came from, however the activity it starts from, needs to have the ability to be closed without effecting the broadcast receiver, so if I unregister it at the onPause() part of the activity, surely this will end the broadcast receiver before it has started?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your concern regarding wasting resources by having the broadcast receiver 'hanging around'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the system handle it. It will be garbage collected as needed and often is quickly. In addition, the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) javadoc states that it will be aggressively killed.

Comment: I have been running a fairly basic app using this current method and it feels to me that the phone runs slow until I choose to clear memory through the task manager. Would this app be causing it ?

Comment: Its possible but there are more causes of slowness, have you also checked available memory and CPU usage?

Comment: Not as yet, I am just concerned that if this app was to be available for general release, it could cause issues on the users phones. The phone , to me , only appeared to run slower at this point but it could be a coincidence with me signing up to Samsung account to check for updates perhaps? . The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S2 so it has a fair amount of Memory and dual CPU.

Comment: Is it also possible to protect a waiting broadcast receiver from been cleared by a task manager application?

Comment: It could be possible that's why understanding memory and CPU usage is only an important starting point to diagnose slowness. Once a broadcast receiver has been removed there is no way to store it for later, an unresolved intent is just thrown away.

Comment: Okay Dan thanks for your input on this I will monitor the phone's status when running the app